# RJ45 console cable specs

Tags: layer1, cable

I need longer RJ45 <-> RJ45 cables to connect my devices to a centralized management console.  It's like 5 meters going go the next racks, at 9600 baud rate.

Can I buy random/cheapest cable from Amazon ?
I guess we don't care about shielded cables for console ?

Comment: It depends on the distance and the speed: how long do you want them and how fast do you run your consoles?

Comment: by console I mean the console port/serial communication/RS232

Comment: I was asking how long you want your cables, and what baud rate you run the console ports.

Comment: okay sorry. it's like 5meters going go the next racks. 9600 baud rate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the main benefits of using relatively slow console speeds such as the default 9600 baud is that you don't need anything special in the way of cabling: almost any kind of cable will work over reasonable distances.

From one rack to another around 5-10 metres, just use whatever cable is convenient.

Experimentally I've used building Cat 3 at approx 100 metres without issue.

[EDIT] This is intended as statements for the toolbox -- ie, what people find in real life doing occasional console activities on routers.  If you're designing real RS-232 systems at any distance, be an engineer and pay attention to cable specs and use, for example, low-capacitance cabling designed for the task.  Alternatively use convertors to 4-wire RS-485 and use your normal structured cabling twisted pair cabling.